# Jira : openCreateIssueDialog is not defined

Tags: events, jira, jira-plugin, atlassian-connect

I am getting:

> Uncaught Reference Error: openCreateIssueDialog is not defined

whenever I am trying to open create issue dialog of Jira. I am using following portion of code.

```
AP.require('jira', function(jira){
  jira.openCreateIssueDialog(function(issues){
      alert(issues[0]['fields']['summary']);
  } , {
      pid: 10000,
      issueType: 1
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like shown in the following:

```
AP.jira.openCreateIssueDialog(function(issues){
  alert(issues[0]['fields']['summary']);
}, {
  pid: 10000,
  issueType: 1,
  fields : {
    summary: "Hello World",
    environment : "My environment",
    priority : 2,
    assignee: "tom",
    reporter: "bob",
    labels : ["Mylabel","MyOtherLabel"],
    description : "My first Issue",
    duedate : "11/Oct/16",
    fixVersions : 10001,
    versions : 10000,
    components : "My component",
    timetracking_originalestimate: "2w",
    timetracking_remainingestimate: "3d",
    worklog_activate: true,
    worklog_timeLogged: "2"
  }
});
```

Note that `AP.require` and `AP.define` are deprecated and will be removed.

From the Atlassian Connect documentation:

> **AP.require and AP.define are deprecated and will be removed after August 2017.**
>
> The available modules can now be called directly from AP, such as AP.request or AP.jira. No alternative will be provided for AP.define. See Migrate to Atlassian Connect JavaScript V5 for more information.

https://developer.atlassian.com/static/connect/docs/latest/concepts/javascript-api.html